# How to get a username in Active Directory and use it in Windows Services?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have tried using :

string name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

but the output is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" when i run it in as windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the output is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" when i run it in as windows service.

Thats because Im going to guess your service is running as system (EG The default), if you need it running as a domain functional account, you need to change its settings so it uses that account to run the service.  Then you'll get returned MyDomain\FuncUser etc.